# Calculate the following series --- need to understand why I have it incorrect

Tags: summation

Okay I know I have the answer incorrect but not sure why...

Calculate the following series:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n 2^j \text{ for } n = 1,2,3,4$$

so I think it would be $2^1 = 2$ but the answer is $3$ and the rest are $7,9,32$... I do not understand how they got $3$. Any guidance will help.

Comment: The sum starts from $j=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) in general is $$\sum_{j=0}^n a^j = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$$

For $a=2$, you get $$\sum_{j=0}^n 2^j = 2^{n+1}-1.$$

---

If your sum begins at $j=1$, $$\sum_{j=1}^n a^j = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}-1=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$$
If you use $a=2$, you get $$\sum_{j=1}^n 2^j =2^{n+1}-2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{j=0}^12^j=2^0+2^1=3
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^22^j=2^0+2^1+2^2=7
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^32^j=2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3=15 \qquad[\text{not }9]
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^42^j=2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4=31 \qquad [\text{not }32]
$$